# Get content of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, contenteditable

how can I get the contents of span ?
I'm looking for a way for all of this to be vanilla, not jQuery

javascript (and a little jQuery)

```
var swear_words_arr=new Array("bad","evil","freak");
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + swear_words_arr.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i' );

function validate_user_text() {
var text = document.getElementById('myInput');
text.text();

if(regex.test(text)) {
    window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
    return false;
}

}
var myVar=setInterval(function(){validate_user_text()},1000);change
```

here's my html

```
<div id="textArea">
<span id="myInput" contenteditable="true">kfjdkfj</span>
</div>
<br />
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="">

<textarea rows="3" cols="40" name="user_text" style="border:2 solid #808080; font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica; font-weight:normal; font-size:10pt" onclick="select_area()"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return validate_user_text();"></form>
```

Thank You

Comment: You asked this 25 minutes ago. Spamming [so] will get you a question ban, especially since your question is off-topic and of little value.

Comment: You could have just used an `<input>` and get the value using `.value`. Save's you from the hassle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
var text = input.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks for not having a confusing answer ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

Taken from MDN:

```
// Given the following HTML fragment:
//   <div id="divA">This is <span>some</span> text</div>

// Get the text content:
var text = document.getElementById("divA").textContent;
// |text| is set to "This is some text".

// Set the text content:
document.getElementById("divA").textContent = "This is some text";
// The HTML for divA is now:
//   <div id="divA">This is some text</div>
```

Comment: textContent is ideal for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue here:

```
var text = document.getElementById('myInput');
text.text();
```

You never assigned the text of the input to any variable.

Following your pattern above, you could do:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('myInput'),
    txt = text.text();
```

The second variable updates the previous variable 'txt' to hold the text of the original 'txt' variable, which was a selector.

You could do this as well (vanilla javascript, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TGqb/)):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('myInput').innerHTML;

//or

var txt = document.getElementById('myInput').textContent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using...

```
text.text();
```

Try using...

```
text.innerHTML;
```

I've only found .text() to work when you're using a jQuery selector.

```
 $('#myInput').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = (document.getElementById("myInput")).innerHTML
```

or the abridged form:

```
var text = $('#myInput').text()
```