# Cannot get the text of a span element using .getText() on a non-angular page

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get the text value of an element `<span>` but it doesn't return anything with `.getText()`

`

```
//spec
var statPage = require('something');

describe('Start', function () {
    describe('Setup', function () {
        it('test quality', function(){
            new statPage().quality();
        });
    });
});


//page object
Sender.prototype.quality = function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    this.verifyPageUrl();
    this.verifyTabName();
};

Sender.prototype.verifyTabName = function () {
    console.log("inside verifyTabName()");

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var tab = element(by.css("span.active-tab-head"));

    browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(tab, 'u4uvpzn4'),     5000).then(function(){
        console.log('inside browser wait');
    });
    tab.getText().then(function(tabFullName) {
        console.log('tab name is : ' + tabFullName);
    });
};

Sender.prototype.verifyPageUrl = function () {
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(text){
        console.log('this is the right page : ' + text);
    });
};
```

`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get content of span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875775/get-content-of-span)

Comment: Where is `getText` defined or is it a protractor thing?

Comment: @Andra it is not a duplicate. This one is actually `protractor`-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something weird was happening coz protractor was not even recognizing `browser.pause()` But, reinstalling protractor fixed the issues!

Answer (score 1):

The code you've presented, looks correct and, I suspect, there could be a timing issue. Let's use [`textToBePresentInElement` Expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement) and wait for `u4uvpzn4` text to be present inside an *active tab*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var tab = element(by.css("span.active-tab-head"));

browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(tab, 'u4uvpzn4'), 5000);
tab.getText().then(function(tabFullName) {
    console.log('tab name is : ' + tabFullName);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that this is a non-angular page. So, would the above code work after setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` ?

Comment: due to some weird reason it fails to work!
`var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var tab = element(by.css("span.active-tab-head"));

browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(tab, 'u4uvpzn4'), 5000).then(function(){
            console.log('inside browser wait');
});

tab.getText().then(function(tabFullName) {
    console.log('tab name is : ' + tabFullName);
});
`

It doesn't display any of the console logs!

Comment: @CodeRJ interesting, please show me the complete test you have (edit the question and post there). Thanks.

Comment: @CodeRJ ah, sure, please remove the `then()` for `browser.wait()` and see if it now would fail with a timeout error, correct? That could mean the element is not getting the desired text - the active tab does not have the `u4uvpzn4` text inside it.

Comment: @alexce but in html above, it shows the text is present!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102734/discussion-between-alecxe-and-coderj).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more dynamic by trying:

```
var tabName = element(by.css('.tab-head.active-tab-head'));
```

The only other issue I could think of off-hand is that you may not have any tabs set to .active-tab-head, which would return an empty string.

Comment: This `span` does not have the `value` attribute.