# How To get values in Span Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make some thing using HTML and js. I want to get the text in span tag like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:search()">
            <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:search()">
            <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:search()">
            <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:search()">
            <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js like this :

```
<script>
   function searchProcessName(){
         var textSearch = document.getElementById("namesearch");
            //Do some thing
   }
</script>
```

it not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get content of span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875775/get-content-of-span)

Comment: The ID attribute should be unique on whole page. Do not use four times the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate id's in your html please note only one id should be there for a element by the way you can use classes for multiple element
Use innerHTML  to get text inside `span`

```
<script>
   function searchProcessName(){
         var textSearch = document.getElementById("namesearch").innerHTML;
            //Do some thing
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `id` must be unique on page, so no elements can have same ID (it means your code is invalid).

Than use [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to get it's text

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple times the same ID. You can't. The ID is a unique identifier thus it could be only present once.

```js
var textSearch = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
for (var i = 0; i < textSearch.length; i++) {
  console.log(textSearch[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:search()">
      <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:search()">
      <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:search()">
      <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:search()">
      <span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of mistakes in your example html ..

1.) ID cannot be same  `<span class="name" id="namesearch">n 1</span>`

2.) your calling different function that your `javascript:search()` but you have declared the function named `searchProcessName()`

please go through example and basics about javascript and html ..

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique 
`document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML`