# How to get the value inside of a <span>?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get the value inside of this `<span>`:

`<span id="timer" class="timer">0</span>`

How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get content of span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875775/get-content-of-span)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spans do not have a value - you will have to use .innerText to get the text content within the span. Refer to (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Note that innerText will give you a string - so if you are planning on using the value for calculationations you will have to use parseInt() to convert it to a number.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('timer').innerText;
console.log(text); // gives "0"
```

```html
<span id="timer" class="timer">0</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using $('#timer').text();  or html(); 
This is jQuery, because it's way more comfortable I recommend using it

Comment: I said using jQuery in general is more comfortable. Learn to read.